# Using pytest to test classes and functions in Jupyter Notebook Files

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, jupyter-notebook, pytest

I am facing an issue while attempting to import the jupyter notebook file `MyNotebook.ipynb` into a pytest test script (`test_add.py`). The test script aims to test the `add` function defined in the `MyNotebook.ipynb` Jupyter Notebook. However, I encounter an `ImportError` with the error message:

```
ImportError while importing test module '/app/test_add.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
test_add.py:1: in <module>
    from MyNotebook import add
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MyNotebook'
```

Steps Taken:

1. I have created a Jupyter Notebook named `MyNotebook.ipynb` containing the `add` function implementation as follows:

```py
def add(a, b):
    return a + b
```

2. I created a pytest test script named `test_add.py`, which aims to test the `add` function from `MyNotebook.ipynb`:

```py
from MyNotebook import add

def test_add():
    assert add(2, 3) == 5
    assert add(0, 0) == 0
    assert add(-1, 1) == 0
```

3. I ran pytest in the project directory using the command `pytest`. However, I encountered an `ImportError` with the message `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MyNotebook'`.

Additional Notes:

- I have already ensured that the `MyNotebook.ipynb` and `test_add.py` files are in the same directory.
- The Python version used is 3.11.4, and pytest version is 7.4.0.
- I suspect there might be an issue with the format of the jupyter notebook importation in `test_add.py`, as it tries to import from a module 'MyNotebook' but cant find it.

I am seeking assistance to resolve the import error and successfully run the pytest test script to test the `add` function in `MyNotebook.ipynb`. Thank you for any insights or suggestions.

Comment: you can't import an .ipynb ... it is essentially just a JSON.

Comment: I would have to turn it into a python file and then execute the test right?

Comment: well, yes. But what problem are you actually trying to solve, why are you trying to run tests on code written in an ipython notebook?

Comment: I am doing a program with data visualisations and so I wanted to use jupyter notebook. I wanted to perform unit testing with pytest along with it during development.

Comment: then you should just write your code in a regular module, then *import that module in your notebook*.

Comment: Oh, true thats a good suggestion I don't know why I didn't think of that.